# Flink : Load resource file in cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am running a Flink code that work well when executed localy (in IntelliJ) but crash when running in a Flink cluster :

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
```

In the initialisation of my job, I load a text file, that is embedded in my jar file with the following code :

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/my_file.txt"))) {
            myObject = new MyClass.Parser().parse(is);
}catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while trying to file : "+e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

The object created from the content of the text file is then used to create my Source and my Sink and also to do some internal computing in a map function.

How can I correctly load this file in cluster mode ?

Edit :

When I replace the code above with

```
myObject = new MyClassParser().parse(FILE_CONTENT_AS_STRING);
```

The code run well. It looks like it is only the loading of the file that cause the error.

Comment: could you post the whole stack trace of Flink crash

Comment: This is the only log I can see when running the JAR through Flink Web Dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you build your code into a jar, the file path no longer can be used to access the file. Instead, you need to use something like `<YourClassName>.class.getResourceAsStream("/my_file.txt")` to get the `InputStream`.